# Why isn't my test not passing for returning elements in an array as a percentage?

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I am returning an array representing the number of views as a percentage and return null if views is null and empty array if views is an empty array
for example, if views = {10, 70, 20, 90}, the total views are 190.
* 10 is 5.26% of 190
* 70 is 36.84% of 190
* 20 is 10.52% of 190
* 90 is 47.36% of 190
I don't need to worry about the EXACT value. The test checks if each value is within 0.01 of the value expected.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong because my test is not passing?

```
public double[] viewsInPercentage() {
    if(views.length==0) {
        return null;
    }
    double watched[] = new double[views.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        watched[i] = ((double)views[i]*100)/getTotalViews();
    }
    return watched;
}
```

Test

```
@BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        currentMethodName = null;
        
        a = new int[] {10,70,20,90,80,5};
        simple = new VideoAnalytics("El Clasico", a);
        
        b = null;
        nullHistory = new VideoAnalytics("Installing Eclipse", b);
        
        c = new int[0]; //empty array
        emptyHistory = new VideoAnalytics("Headphones Review", c);
        
        d = new int[] {10,10,20,10,20,30,10,20,30,40,5,40,50,60,80,70,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180};
        longHistory = new VideoAnalytics("Practical exam walkthrough", d);
    }

@Test @Order(6) @Graded(description="viewsInPercentage", marks=8)
public void testViewsInPercentage() {
    assertNull(nullHistory.viewsInPercentage());
    assertNotNull(emptyHistory.viewsInPercentage());
    assertEquals(0, emptyHistory.viewsInPercentage().length);
    
    for(int i=0; i < simple.views.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(simple.views[i] * 100.0 / simple.getTotalViews(), simple.viewsInPercentage()[i], 0.01);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < longHistory.views.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(longHistory.views[i] * 100.0 / longHistory.getTotalViews(), longHistory.viewsInPercentage()[i], 0.01);
    }
    
    currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the *test* is correct? Please show the test code as well.

Comment: Added the tests

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `null` and empty output for `null` and empty input respectively, the code needs to be fixed:

```java
public double[] viewsInPercentage() {
    if(null == views) {
        return null;
    }
    double[] watched = new double[views.length];
    int totalViews = getTotalViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) { // the loop won't execute for empty input
        watched[i] = views[i] * 100.0 / totalViews;
    }
    return watched;
}
```

Also, `getTotalViews` should be checked that it returns correct total of all views:

```java
public int getTotalViews() {
    return null == views ? 0 : Arrays.stream(views).sum();
}
```